# What are the boot requirements for an IoT device for the automotive industry?

Tags: hardware, software

Are there any specifications for a IoT device that's targeted for the automotive industry? I refer to a standard that puts constraints on boot and restart times for both the HW and SW?

Let's say I want to build an IoT platform that starts the AC once it's too cold or a device that makes the car horn goes off if it detects a possible collision.

What kind of booting times, restart time or any other requirements I need to take into account.

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you want to attempt here. Very generally, for automotive, you need to demonstrate with a high degree of certainty, how many failures you expect, how you will handle them, and how significant the impact of the ones you miss are. This is also off-topic.

Comment: You would not normally use a desktop operating system for this; the primary reason you may see one in some *home* devices is to speak everyday IP networking protocols, but something in a car would speak CAN or maybe BLE to cooperate with a phone.  Arguably, this isn't even an IoT question, but rather an automotive one.

Comment: Context is really missing here, are those homework ? University project ? if you work at an automotive design shop they should have better specifications

Comment: @Rsf it's for a startup I am starting to work on.

Comment: Did you ask them ? anyway, I suppose there's a big difference between the critical and the none critical systems in a car. My Nissan connect takes many seconds to boot, while the engine management computer probably boots in a second or less.

Comment: This looks like an interesting starting point: [sae](http://www.sae.org/smartgrid/p90475.pdf)

Comment: I don't understand why some people voted to close this question as off-topic. It's about the design of an IoT device. I voted to close as too broad, because the applicable requirements depend on what the device is used for (critical functionality, interacts with critical components without giving critical output, not connected to the car's main buses, …).

Comment: @Gilles automative electronics is really its own area, of longstanding tradition, and distinct from IoT.  Passenger compartment temperature control is a standard auto feature; collision warning is an idea going back more than 30 years.  Possibly if you had a transponder based *cooperative* collision warning scheme that might start to fit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Automotive is often its own world in terms of physical manufacturing (due to environmental and reliability constraints that don't exist in many other scenarios) and in terms of marketing. In terms of hardware and software architecture, it isn't so distinct, and trying to move to more “standard” parts (especially software). Excluding automotive from IoT doesn't make sense from either an automotive or IoT perspective (not that “IoT perspective” means anything, given how poorly defined it is).

Comment: The point is that the things being done are not IoT "actions" but rather traditional automotive ones.  Nor are the technologies used (CAN, etc) typically associated with IoT.   If your car were collaborating with your smart home, that might be a different matter.  Or possibly if cars were collaborating with each other via transponders, but that's likely to be thought of as its own "smart traffic" field rather than mainstream IoT.  Defining what is and isn't IoT often means looking at "intent" and "market segment" - it's not just about technologies, because if it were, it would be meaningless.

Answer (score 7):

- Yes, there are standards, they are called *Automotive safety standards*, you can start with [ISO26262](https://www.iso.org/standard/43464.html).
- Regarding the boot time, this is usually a requirement of the car manufacturer. However this can be determined asking the following question.

In case of fail while driving, how much time the system needs to reach a safety state? 
This is, speed 0 and out of the way to avoid other cars/trucks that come behind to collide with you. Considering the speed the car is driving and the distance to the obstacle, with this you get the maximum time the system can take to stop the car. Now, in that period the system can fail and restart. Therefore the system recovers insanely quick or there is a redundant service
that kicks in when the other is down. The last is the most realistic.

Autonomous driving cars are reaching a safety requirements compare to the airplanes, or even more complex, because the environment they work has many more factors, traffic lights, traffic signs, people, cars, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The **IoT devices are normally non real-time machines**.

**These devices** will be connected to the controllers and readers to **collect data**. And would help with the best route while driving. or control the cooling system wrt the weather forecast(Chuckle).

The functions of the automobile that has to happen in real-time are the operation of auto-brake, airbags etc. (During collision). These are better to have their control system in the vehicle itself, rather than over the internet.

The boot time for a Hard real-time application should be as minimal as possible(in milliseconds). But the IoT system would not be that fast because, it has many functionalities like the Internet Capability, GPS system, etc.

For the AC application that you mentioned, It might be feasible to use an IoT control system!

Hope it helps.

Comment: this link [here](https://blog.pusher.com/what-is-real-time/) could be a reference.

Comment: IoT endpoints _are_ real-time. Saw one launched last week with flash-based configuration memory (for peripheral state) so it's live from reset.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Maybe a very new tech. but even-though it starts immediately, internet takes time to connect... right.

Comment: it can also be `firm` or `soft real-time` but may not be hard real-time.

Comment: Sure, the WAN needs to be asynchronous to local operation, but you'd expect fallback/failsafe operation within a few hundred cycles of reset. A few ms at the very most.